# cscope and ctags files seems to cause kernel build failure

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, makefile

I'm working on a recently cloned [linux-kernel](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git) , with `KBUILD_OUTPUT=~/linux-source-root/build` defined, and a `make defconfig` generated `.config` file.

Building with `make bzImage -j4` worked with no issues as expected.

I then created `cscope` and `ctags` files:

```
ARCH=x86 make cscope
ARCH=x86 make tags
```

That worked ok as well, and created the files.
However, the next build after that causes a build failure with:

```
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
Using .. as source for kernel
.. is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
```

How can I build the kernel, while keeping my `cscope`/`ctags` files intact?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that, but perhaps you could move the generated cscope and ctags files out of the way, run a `make mrproper` in the source directory, and move the previously generated cscope and ctags files back where they came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cscope` and `ctags` files have nothing to do with the error you are facing. This message was printed from kernel top-level `Makefile`:

```sh
$(Q)if [ -f $(srctree)/.config -o -d $(srctree)/include/config ]; then \
    echo >&2 "  $(srctree) is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'"; \
    echo >&2 "  in the '$(srctree)' directory.";\
    /bin/false; \
fi;
```

So it's either you have `.config` file or `include/config` directory in your kernel source tree directory, which prevents you from building kernel. You should remove previous build by performing `make mrproper` command in kernel source tree directory before running new build.